# Down to a strange and charming story about brothers who hit the bottom, until they got up to the top

Tags: story

My name is Ulysses. I'm the tallest of six brothers and this is our story.

Our father, Henry, was a very huge fan of greek mythology, but he never could imagine that we, his very sons, would live an Odyssey.

Like I said, I am the tallest and oldest among us; watching the scene from up there gave me the best view of what happened.

My youngest brother, Brontes, is one of the most influential and rebellious mass inciter of the time. "Pushing them away from the bottom" is his catch phrase; he goes from city to city trying to raise consensus.

That's why Brontes can't stand our brother Thanathos, the second born, since he represents all he is fighting against. Thanathos has become the president of a huge multinational corporation.  We can safely say he has reached the top of his career. He has become a bit selfish and stingy.

And still, Thanatos was the only one who could help Deimos, the third in line. His small shop has recently declared bankruptcy, and he has started going down to a spiral of depression. If Thanathos helped him maybe all of this could have been avoided.

The penultimate of us is Castor. He is a not-so-famous showman, only known for his charm during the live shows. He is obviously conceited and relates very well with Thanathos, with whom he shares career objectives and common thoughts.

And, last but not least, there's Sarpedon. Our poor brother suffered mild brain damage when we were young, during a childhood fight with Thanathos. Since then his behaviour can only be described by one word: strange. Not capable of getting a job, he is taken care of by Thanathos, who feels guilty for what happened, although he will never admit it.

Every year we reunite. And every year we fight about the most utterly stupid things, like brothers do.

But last time was different.
Brontes was mad at Thanathos and in part at Castor for not helping Deimos in his bankruptcy. As rebellious as ever, he punched Thanathos right in the nose, breaking it.

Nothing similar had ever happened in previous meetings.
Since then we reunited in 2 groups of 3 people.

But now that I managed to get them all together again, seeing Brontes and Thanathos hug, I can say that our bonds are stronger than ever!

Who are we? Who is our father?

**HINT**

> Most of the content is a filler for the story. You are still able to find the answer; the wording is the key.

Comment: The answer is clear just from the title :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably

> quarks. The six flavours are: Up (Ulysses), Down (Deimos), Top (Thanatos), Bottom (Brontes), Strange (Sarpedon) and Charm (Castor).

and your father is probably

> Murray Gell-Mann, the father of the quark model (George Zweig also developed the theory independently, but he proposed the name "ace")

It's cool seeing

> the kinds of particle formation you were hinting at =)

Comment: I think the father is more likely to be [Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Way_Kendall), like it says.

Comment: Oh, actually I wasn't thinking to any of them as fathers, rather I played on the fact that quarks are Fermions... I like @Geobits version more tough :) Also, the answer is correct!

Comment: Btw all the story runs around the title, which is what startled me the question